SessionState DB missing appid in table 'ASPStateTempApplications'
We are using session state DB 'ASPState' in order to store the sessions from our application. But after creating the ASPState DB and configuring with the application with the following string, appid isn't created in the application table as attached in the screenshot though the sessions are getting stored into the session table.
<add name="SqlServerInMemorySession" connectionString="Data Source=<<>>;Initial Catalog=ASPState; User Id=<<>>; Password=<<>>;Connect Timeout=150;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=true " />


Can we continue with no appid?
How to get the appid created in the ASPStateTempApplications table?
Kindly help.


Disconnected the application
Then dropped ASPState DB
Recreated the DB
Connected with the application
Did that for 3 times - but with no luck.

Completely unrelated to the question, but Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=true in your connection string makes little sense. If your connection isn't encrypted (poor idea), then there is no certificate to trust. Really you should be using Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False and get a certificate applied to your server. If you need some time to get that cert, then you could (temporarily) use the self signed one and trust that certificate until you get a proper one.

Thanks for the @Thom A - will consider it - I just acquired from app end developers and I am in mid of learning DBA thing.
